# forwarding from one jsp page to another jsp apge?

Tags: jsp

i developed a project on student marks system.in this project their is one html page which asks user to enter the roll number and when we press submit button on that page it moves a jsp page .on that jsp page it retrieve marks regarding the particular roll number and displays the marks and i write another jsp which will calculate the percentage of the marks.
from the previous jsp page the data needs to pass.i use  for that.when i use the jsp forward the contrlol directly goes to the percentage page without presenting the marks

but i need to present the both marks as well as percentage

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. If you need to present both marks and percentage you can just combine the code in a single page. If you want to split in two consecutive pages, please be aware of the possibilities of

- HTML forms and [HttpServletRequest.getParameter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to transfer data.
- the possibility not only to map servlet, but jsp files as well in your web.xml (servlet, replace servlet-class with jsp-file and enter relative path).
- the option to develop a custom tag for clearly defined views.

I don't know how appropiate my suggestions are, but at least the first and second will help you to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you search for `jsp:include`?

If yes, take a look at [this](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref1112.html) and [this](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro8.html) documentations for the command.